# Mocha&Chai: Writing assertion

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am writing test cases using mocha and chai for the first time. This is a very simple response returned by my service:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Done"
}
```

I have written assertion like this:

```
describe('GET /TestService', function() {
    it('should run successfully.', function(done) {
        request
            .get('/myApp/TestService/')
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
                expect(res.body.message).to.equal('Done');
            });
    });
});
```

When I execute the test it returns:
**Uncaught AssertionError: expected undefined to equal true**

What is wrong with this? This is my first ever encounter with Mocha and Chai. Maybe I am missing a very basic thing. This is just the first step. Can someone push me forward?

Comment: Have you checked the `res`, what u are getting?

Comment: @kgangadhar, response is included in the question.

Comment: Here `.end(function(err, res) {` inside the unit test, are you getting expected response?

Comment: Please try JSON.parse(res.body).success